# How do I change the UI after a login with Google Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Ok, so I am building an extension in Google Chrome and I have it so that when my extension's icon is clicked a login form pops up (default_popup). When they fill this form out it sends an ajax request to my server, authenticates, and sends back my token.

So far so good.

Now, how do I change the popup to show something else now that it is authenticated?

I suspect that it is a really simple problem to solve, but I've been looking around for hours for a solution and I can't find one.

EDIT:
Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
$(document).on('submit','#login',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email'),
        password = $('#password');
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://myurl.com/api/request?email='+email+'&password='+password,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output) {
        if (output.status == true) {
            api_key = output.results.api_key;
            api_secret = output.results.api_secret;
            localStorage.setItem('api_key',output.results.api_key);
            localStorage.setItem('api_secret',output.results.api_secret);
        }
    }); });
```

I want to rerender the output to some other content when the login is done. Is there a clean way of doing this? Usually I would use handlebarsjs, but apparently extensions don't support it without sandboxing.

Comment: Well, without the specifics (what needs to be shown, what is the exact problem) only a generic answer could be given like `just do it`? :-)

Comment: @wOxxOm  I want to change <html>login form</html> to <html>Logged In content</html> when the user is authenticated.

Comment: show code and what you tried. it should be no different than changing a regular html page with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as hiding and showing elements with JavaScript. Have the `#logged-in` div hidden by default. Once authentication is complete, hide `#login-form` and show `#logged-in`. Assuming that you'll be storing some sort of token once they're logged in, you could store this in localStorage and check for it every time your popup.html loads. If it's there, show `#logged-in`, if it's not, show `#login-form`.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="login-form">
      <!-- All your login form content -->
    </div>
    <div id="logged-in">
      <!-- All your content once authenticated-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I wanted to achieve. I ended up using Mustache on the front end to make the process cleaner.